# XSLT - Add new node Conditionally

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <section id="1">This is <style type="normal">first</style> chapter</section>
    <section id="2">This is <style type="normal">second</style> chapter</section>
    <section id="3">This is <style type="normal">third</style> chapter</section>
    <section id="4">This is <style type="normal">forth</style> chapter</section>
    <section id="5">This is <style type="normal">fifth</style> chapter</section>
    <section id="6">This is <style type="normal">sixth</style> chapter</section>
    <section id="7">This is <style type="normal">seventh</style> chapter</section>
</doc>
```

what I need is add new node named `<newNode>` conditionally. the xsl I've written is follows,

```
<xsl:variable name="var" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>

    <xsl:template match="section[position()=last()]">
        <section id="{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </section>
        <newNode>New Node</newNode>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[position()=3]">
        <section id="{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </section>
        <newNode>New Node</newNode>
    </xsl:template>
```

My requirement is if `var` value is `true()` add new node under section 3 and if `var` value is `false()` add new node under final section node. I've written to add `<newNode>` under both section 3 and final section. but cannot think of method to conditionally check var value and add `<newNode>` accordingly.

How can I do this task in xslt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
<xsl:template match="section[not($var) and position()=last()]">
    <section id="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>
    <newNode>New Node</newNode>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[$var and position()=3]">
    <section id="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>
    <newNode>New Node</newNode>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplified version of @MartinHonnen 's answer

```
<xsl:template match="section[position()=(if ($var) then 3 else last())]">
    <section id="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>
    <newNode>New Node</newNode>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Variation in style of Martin Honnen's answer: in case there was reason to limit `match` to node selection, you could also place whatever depends on `$var` in a conditional inside the templates,

```
<xsl:template match="...">
  <xsl:if test="not($var)">
    <section id="{@id}">
    ...
```